# Missing admin page when Mezzanine site deployed to Heroku

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, mezzanine

The admin page does not appear for whatever reason when i navigate to the associated URL. Instead I get a page not found page.  With the default message "error: an error occured"

The weird thing is that the page shows up when i run heroku local or when I run the app locally without heroku.

I suspect this is an issue with mezzanine URLS.  But im not sure how they work :| .

My database setting in settings.py

```py
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.parse('postgres://blahblahtheurl')}
```

I also made some changes to the static settings:

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Full filesystem path to the project.
PROJECT_APP_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PROJECT_APP = os.path.basename(PROJECT_APP_PATH)
PROJECT_ROOT = BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_APP_PATH)

# Every cache key will get prefixed with this value - here we set it to
# the name of the directory the project is in to try and use something
# project specific.
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = PROJECT_APP

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, STATIC_URL.strip("/"))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

my installed apps and middleware:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.redirects",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "mezzanine.boot",
    "mezzanine.conf",
    "mezzanine.core",
    "mezzanine.generic",
    "mezzanine.pages",
    "mezzanine.blog",
    "mezzanine.forms",
    "mezzanine.galleries",
    "mezzanine.twitter",
    "myblog",
    "gunicorn"
    # "mezzanine.accounts",
)

# List of middleware classes to use. Order is important; in the request phase,
# these middleware classes will be applied in the order given, and in the
# response phase the middleware will be applied in reverse order.
MIDDLEWARE = (
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.UpdateCacheMiddleware",

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # Uncomment if using internationalisation or localisation
    # 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    "mezzanine.core.request.CurrentRequestMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.AdminLoginInterfaceSelectorMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.SitePermissionMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
)
```

Heroku logs produces no errors...

Thanks for any response!

~EDIT~
This is my urls.py file located in adrientremblay(my project root)>adrientremblay

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from mezzanine.core.views import direct_to_template
from mezzanine.pages.views import page
import mezzanine.blog.views as blog_views
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.i18n import set_language

from mezzanine.core.views import direct_to_template
from mezzanine.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

# Add the urlpatterns for any custom Django applications here.
# You can also change the ``home`` view to add your own functionality
# to the project's homepage.

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    # Change the admin prefix here to use an alternate URL for the
    # admin interface, which would be marginally more secure.
    url("^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.USE_MODELTRANSLATION:
    urlpatterns += [
        url('^i18n/$', set_language, name='set_language'),
    ]

urlpatterns += [
    # We don't want to presume how your homepage works, so here are a
    # few patterns you can use to set it up.

    # HOMEPAGE AS STATIC TEMPLATE
    # ---------------------------
    # This pattern simply loads the index.html template. It isn't
    # commented out like the others, so it's the default. You only need
    # one homepage pattern, so if you use a different one, comment this
    # one out.

    # url("^$", direct_to_template, {"template": "index.html"}, name="home"),

    # HOMEPAGE AS AN EDITABLE PAGE IN THE PAGE TREE
    # ---------------------------------------------
    # This pattern gives us a normal ``Page`` object, so that your
    # homepage can be managed via the page tree in the admin. If you
    # use this pattern, you'll need to create a page in the page tree,
    # and specify its URL (in the Meta Data section) as "/", which
    # is the value used below in the ``{"slug": "/"}`` part.
    # Also note that the normal rule of adding a custom
    # template per page with the template name using the page's slug
    # doesn't apply here, since we can't have a template called
    # "/.html" - so for this case, the template "pages/index.html"
    # should be used if you want to customize the homepage's template.
    # NOTE: Don't forget to import the view function too!

    # url("^$", mezzanine.pages.views.page, {"slug": "/"}, name="home"),

    # HOMEPAGE FOR A BLOG-ONLY SITE
    # -----------------------------
    # This pattern points the homepage to the blog post listing page,
    # and is useful for sites that are primarily blogs. If you use this
    # pattern, you'll also need to set BLOG_SLUG = "" in your
    # ``settings.py`` module, and delete the blog page object from the
    # page tree in the admin if it was installed.
    # NOTE: Don't forget to import the view function too!

    url("^$", blog_views.blog_post_list, name="home"),

    # MEZZANINE'S URLS
    # ----------------
    # ADD YOUR OWN URLPATTERNS *ABOVE* THE LINE BELOW.
    # ``mezzanine.urls`` INCLUDES A *CATCH ALL* PATTERN
    # FOR PAGES, SO URLPATTERNS ADDED BELOW ``mezzanine.urls``
    # WILL NEVER BE MATCHED!

    # If you'd like more granular control over the patterns in
    # ``mezzanine.urls``, go right ahead and take the parts you want
    # from it, and use them directly below instead of using
    # ``mezzanine.urls``.
    url("^", include("mezzanine.urls")),

    # MOUNTING MEZZANINE UNDER A PREFIX
    # ---------------------------------
    # You can also mount all of Mezzanine's urlpatterns under a
    # URL prefix if desired. When doing this, you need to define the
    # ``SITE_PREFIX`` setting, which will contain the prefix. Eg:
    # SITE_PREFIX = "my/site/prefix"
    # For convenience, and to avoid repeating the prefix, use the
    # commented out pattern below (commenting out the one above of course)
    # which will make use of the ``SITE_PREFIX`` setting. Make sure to
    # add the import ``from django.conf import settings`` to the top
    # of this file as well.
    # Note that for any of the various homepage patterns above, you'll
    # need to use the ``SITE_PREFIX`` setting as well.

    # ("^%s/" % settings.SITE_PREFIX, include("mezzanine.urls"))

]

# Adds ``STATIC_URL`` to the context of error pages, so that error
# pages can use JS, CSS and images.
handler404 = "mezzanine.core.views.page_not_found"
handler500 = "mezzanine.core.views.server_error"
```

This seems to be more or less be what the example urls.py file looks like.  However i created an app called myblog with an admin.py and a models.py which i used to add some fields to some mezzanine models and them update the admin interface.  Maybe this is the issue?

admin.py:

```py
from copy import deepcopy
from django.contrib import admin
from mezzanine.blog.admin import BlogPostAdmin
from mezzanine.blog.models import BlogPost
from mezzanine.pages.admin import PageAdmin
from .models import MyBlogPage

# Injecting field into blogadmin

blog_fieldsets = deepcopy(BlogPostAdmin.fieldsets)
blog_fieldsets[0][1]["fields"].insert(-2, "tagline")

class MyBlogPostAdmin(BlogPostAdmin):
    fieldsets = blog_fieldsets
admin.site.unregister(BlogPost)
admin.site.register(BlogPost, MyBlogPostAdmin)

# Regestering custom page to pageadmin

admin.site.register(MyBlogPage, PageAdmin)
```

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page
from mezzanine.core.models import RichText

# The members of Page will be inherited by the Author model, such
# as title, slug, etc. For authors we can use the title field to
# store the author's name. For our model definition, we just add
# any extra fields that aren't part of the Page model, in this
# case, date of birth.

class MyBlogPage(Page, RichText):
    tagline = models.TextField()
    cover = models.ImageField()
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO. What are the values in your urls.py file and also what is the BASE_URL value in your settings.py file set to?  Please check that you have the mezzanine path included in your urls.py file, here is an example https://github.com/lorin/mezzanine-example/blob/master/urls.py

Comment: Hi thanks for the speedy response.  I updated by question in reply.

Comment: setting debug to true fixed the problem for some reason...  I suppose debug mode enables some simplified mezzanine urls?